# After using self sizing cells reloadData doesn't work anymore

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift, autolayout

I have a UITableView with a custom cell. There is a Button, one label and one hidden label in the cell. I want the hidden label be visible after clicking the button. But when I am using self sizing cells I can't reload my tableView after setting the hidden label to visible.

The self sizing cells are working just fine with these two lines of code in the viewDidLoad() function.

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 68.0
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

This is my ViewController class:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Self sizing cells
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 68.0
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.leftLabel.text = "Left Label"
    cell.centerLabel.text = "I am the center label and I need a little more words because I am supposed to be a wrap content. I hope this is enough"
    cell.button.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    return cell
}

func buttonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    var button: UIButton = sender as! UIButton
    let indexPath: NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: button.tag, inSection: 0)
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.centerLabel.hidden = false
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
}
```

As soon as I call

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 68.0
```

the reloadData call in the buttonAction function doesn't work anymore.

Can anybody help me out with this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: why do you reload your tableView data after you click the button?

Comment: because the ui doesn't update if i don't reload the tableView. If i delete this line: self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 68.0, the button action and reload works fine. but the cell doesn't get the height from its content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You use cellForRowAtIndexPath to grab the cell at that position in the tableView, not dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

```
func buttonAction(sender: UIButton) {
    var indexPath:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow:sender.tag, inSection: 0)
    var cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.centerLabel.hidden = false
}
```

Then if you want to hide the centerLabel when your cells are reused, add this method in your CustomCell class

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    self.centerLabel.hidden = true
}
```

Comment: Also, make sure your auto-layout constraints are correct if you want self sizing cells. Particularly, the labels need to be pinned to the bottom of the cell. The labels should also contain 0 lines so they can resize on their own. ...Just things to consider

Answer (score 0):

After reloadData, your cell.centerLabel.hidden is also invalidated.
As you dont't change the centerLable.hidden in cellForXXX, the centerLable-hidden cell will be at anywhere in your table.

Comment: but If i delete this line: self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 68.0, the button action and reload works fine. but the cell doesn't get the height from its content.